# Meta tags not helping responsive design on Android

Tags: android, jquery, css

I've been doing responsive design for a while now and I still can't figure out why my sites are messed up sometimes on Android devices. Here's a comparison of Android (left phone) vs iPhone (right phone): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sZK3.jpg. A lot of the media queries are not working at all - besides the menu problem that is shown, a contact form at the bottom (not pictured) is wider than it should be, causing the rest of the page to be smaller and not cover the whole screen. A few others are working as well.

I've read quite a few stackoverflow answers on this topic as well already.

I've used the following meta tag for mobile devices (which I've found online when researching to fix this problem):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

I've also used a couple of jQuery functions I made with window resize, like so:

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    var nav = $( "nav ul" ); 
    var w = $(window).width();  
    if(w > 700 && nav.is(':hidden')) {  
        nav.show(); 
    }  else if (w < 700) {
        $(".logo img").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $('nav').css("position", "fixed");
        $("#totop").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Besides these things, all of my @media queries are pretty standard as far as I know. The website is kstardesigns.com

Thanks!

Comment: not sure how this would make a difference..

Comment: i made a trial page for you http://rachelgallen.com/kcstar/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the effort but your page has the same problem - the breakpoint isn't the problem, it must be the jquery function not working properly on Android

Answer (score 0):

Try to use more relative width in your css files or load a different css file according to the screen with media queries.
Using javascript for example like:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches)
```

To find out if you're on the phone and then do some edits with jquery for example.

But I think the best way is to make it all in css if possible and avoid such a workarounds.